# How to place 2 images in one place Flutter

Tags: flutter, image, flutter-layout

I am completely new to flutter and I have to do something like this.

[image: this]

And for the second part, my right image is made from the left image and another image that color is blue.

**Don't be confused!**
I am going to explain in a better way:
first, I have to place these 2 images in
a row(something like ***FrameLayout*** in android)

AND
The right image has been made from an image that is left image ***And*** another image color(Image that has only 1 color)

*I hope you got it*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your issue is about overlapping two widgets, you can use `Stack` to handle it.

Comment: @AmirAndroidDeveloper You can use Positioned child as a children of Stack and set top, right, ...

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `Stack` with `Positioned` to do this:
Here is the Example with icons:

```
class StackExample extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(),
      body:  new Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          height: 500.0,
          width: 500.0,
          // alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
          child: new Stack(
            //alignment:new Alignment(x, y)
            children: <Widget>[
              new Icon(Icons.notifications, size: 36.0, color: const Color.fromRGBO(218, 165, 32, 1.0)),
              new Positioned(
                left: 20.0,
                child: new Icon(Icons.notifications, size: 36.0, color: const Color.fromRGBO(218, 165, 32, 1.0)),
              ),
              new Positioned(
                left:40.0,
                child: new Icon(Icons.notifications, size: 36.0, color: const Color.fromRGBO(218, 165, 32, 1.0)),
              )

            ],
          ),
        ),
      )
    ;
  }
}


class StackExample extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(),
      body:  new Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          height: 500.0,
          width: 500.0,
          // alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
          child: new Stack(
            //alignment:new Alignment(x, y)
            children: <Widget>[
              new Container(
                decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                  boxShadow: [
                    new BoxShadow(
                      blurRadius: 5.0,
                      offset: const Offset(3.0, 0.0),
                      color: Colors.grey,
                    )
                  ]
                ),
                child: new Icon(Icons.notifications, size: 36.0, color: const Color.fromRGBO(218, 165, 32, 1.0))),
              new Positioned(
                left: 20.0,
                child: new Container(
                  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                  boxShadow: [
                    new BoxShadow(
                      blurRadius: 5.0,
                      offset: const Offset(3.0, 0.0),
                      color: Colors.grey,
                    )
                  ]
                ),
                  child: new Icon(Icons.notifications, size: 36.0, color: const Color.fromRGBO(218, 165, 32, 1.0))),
              ),
              new Positioned(
                left:40.0,
                child: new Container(
                  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                  boxShadow: [
                    new BoxShadow(
                      blurRadius: 5.0,
                      offset: const Offset(3.0, 0.0),
                      color: Colors.grey,
                    )
                  ]
                )
                  ,child: new Icon(Icons.notifications, size: 36.0, color: const Color.fromRGBO(218, 165, 32, 1.0))),
              )

            ],
          ),
        ),
      )
    ;
  }
}
```